# make div scoll untill it reaches top of page then fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

let's get straight to the point:

My code looks like the following:

```
<div id="keep_up">
    <div id="thread_menu">
        <div id="new_thread">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my css:

```
#keep_up {
    position: fixed;
    width: 13%;
}

 #thread_menu{
     height: 80vh;
     width: 100%;
     float: left;
     position: relative;
}
```

Now i use this for a forum. and this is basically to show the active and new threads on the side of the screen.

However. When watching a thread, the header disappears (Wich makes sense because we are scrolling down).

but i want the thread menu to stay on my side (So that it is always visible).  In this case that is happening because my keep_up div has position: fixed. But i only see half of the thread menu becuase it is too long and won't scroll up.

*My question:*

I want the thread menu to scroll up, untill it reaches the top of my window. From then on i want it to stay there.

How do i do this?

I saw a few examples but none of them worked for me.

EDIT: Code i tried:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js">
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var margin = null;
        $(window).on("scroll", function () {

            var scrollHeight = $(document).height(),
                scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
                offsetBottom = 110, // Offset depending on the height of the footer
                offsetTop = 100, // Offset depending on the height of the header
                positionTop = $(".keep_up").offset().top,
                affix;


            if (margin != null && (scrollTop + margin <= positionTop)) {
                // The sidebar has reached the bottom and is still on the bottom
                affix = false;
            } else if (positionTop + $(".keep_up").height() >= scrollHeight - offsetBottom) {
                // The sidebar has reached the bottom
                affix = 'bottom';
            } else if (scrollTop <= offsetTop) {
                // The sidebar has reached the top
                affix = 'top';
            } else {
                // The sidebar is midway
                affix = false;
            }
            // If the sidebar hasnot changed his state, return;
            if ($(".keep_up").hasClass('at' + (affix ? '-' + affix : ''))) return;

            if (affix == 'bottom') {
                margin = positionTop - scrollTop;
            } else {
                margin = null;
            }
            // If the related class is added to the div
            $(".keep_up").removeClass('at at-top at-bottom').addClass('at' + (affix ? '-' + affix : ''))

        });
    });
</script>
```

And the CSS:

```
.keep_up{
    /*position: fixed;*/
    width: 13%;
}

.keep_up.at {
    top: 1px;
    position: fixed;
}

.keep_up.at-top{
}

.keep_up.at-bottom {
    top: 438px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Like i said, I tried a few examples (all that i can find) and both did not work for me. ive been working on this only thing now for about 3 hours. So i think it's okay to ask help and i'm not letting people write the whole thing for me. Just asking help Also i don't get:  Come back with You code. This is the code i have written.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fixed scroll div after certain height and stop after reach other div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626397/how-to-fixed-scroll-div-after-certain-height-and-stop-after-reach-other-div)

Comment: @Mitch you need to show us the jquery that you have tried and tell us why it did not work.  As it stands your question shows no attempt at doing this and looks like a please write this code for me question

Comment: Will make an edit @Pete

Answer (score 0):

modify this on HTML:

```
<div id="prevent"></div>
<div id="keep_up" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">
```

Add this CSS:

```
.affix{position: fixed !important; top:0px; z-index:999;}
.affixpatch{margin-top:100px !important;}
```

this will fix the div when you scroll down 200px. Change data-offset-top value to reach it on different break point.
.affixpatch is a class that will be loaded with next jquery function. it prevents to hide content behind top fixed div. Change margin-top to another value if this don't solves the "hide content" problem that always generate affixing divs.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
    var header = $(".affix");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 200) {
            $('#prevent').addClass("affixpatch");
        } else {
            $('#prevent').removeClass("affixpatch");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope it helps. If not, you may have some class that rewrite or impede the correct function of this affix.

I've tested this hundreds of times, usually to fix navbars.

**SCROLL:**
Using overflow to scroll content:

```
#keep_up{
   max-height:400px;
   width: auto;
   overflow:auto;}
```

This will scroll the content inside #keep_up div (or use it in another one)
NOTE: you must declare a fixed max height for this div. Set max-width only if you need.
You can use %, em, rem... no need to be px for fix the max witdth. (to get a responsive effect, use responsive measurements)

Comment: Does not work :/ It does not scroll. I will check if other classes do something, but i don't think so

Comment: oh sorry, i forget scroll :P
letme edit it, refresh in 5min

Comment: With overflow auto, it just turns the overview in a scrollable view xD

Comment: of course, add this at the div that you want to scroll. (this will make that div  scrollable only if necessary (if the content inside causes overflow).
Sorry, i forget to say that you must add those styles into .affix class to only use overflow auto when it's fixed (sticky). 
If it causes overflow auto on non-sticky situation, restore it on scroll top adding overflow:none on this situation. (i'm doing all your homework hehe)
Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your scenario correctly, the way to do this might be to use jQuery (or native JS, but you've tagged jQuery so I'm assuming that's in play).

There's a plugin that handles this kind of thing: http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/

I'd suggest you look at the plugin source code to see how it works - an event handler function on `$(window).scroll()` which then toggles classes on your `#thread_menu` to fix it in place. To keep your code lightweight, you probably don't need everything the plugin provides.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at that.