# Overlapping divs using .position() method of jquery not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make one div appear on other div in such a way that they overlap each other. I'm using .position() method of jquery.

I've seen this method in this question [CSS position element "fixed" inside scrolling container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261270/css-position-element-fixed-inside-scrolling-container)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".blue").position({
    my: "right top",
    at: "left center",
    of: ".red"
  });
});
```

```css
.red,
.blue {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blue">
</div>
<div class="red">
</div>
```

Comment: @TylerRoper
.red, .blue {
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    .red {
        background: red;
    }
    .blue {
        background: blue;
    }

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of [`.position()`](https://api.jqueryui.com/position/) that you're using is not a standard jQuery feature; it comes from [jQuery UI](https://code.jquery.com/ui/).

If you include jQuery UI in your code (after jQuery), it behaves as you'd expect.

If you want `blue` to not concern itself with window boundaries, you can apply `collision: none` as I have below. Additionally, I've changed your `float: left;` to a `position: absolute;`.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".blue").position({
    my: "right top",
    at: "left center",
    of: ".red",
    collision: "none"
  });
});
```

```css
.red,
.blue {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="blue">
</div>
<div class="red">
</div>
```